# What is the meaning of &amp with regard to the test command?

Tags: command-line, test

I learned about the command line command **test** and read a few examples. 
One of them was obscure to me:

```
 test 100 -gt 99 &amp;&amp; echo "Yes, that's true." || echo "No, that's false."
```

I understand it to this point:

```
test 100 -gt 99
```

evaluates whether 100 is greater than 99

```
echo "Yes, that's true." || echo "No, that's false."
```

If the expression turns out to be true do the command on the left of the double pipe symbol, otherwise do the right one.

I could not find any hint onto the **&amp** expression in the manual.

What is its purpose?

Comment: It's a [double-escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) `&`. It should say `&&`, not `&amp;&amp;`.

Comment: Today you'll learn: [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&amp;` doesn't mean anything to `test`, it's the [HTML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) for the *amp*ersand `&`, which has a special meaning in HTML so it cannot be presented as-is. Where ever that snippet came from, the presentation is broken.

Decoding that character, the line should be

```
test 100 -gt 99 && echo "Yes..." || echo "No..."
```

`&&` and `||` still don't have anything to do with `test` itself, but are conditional constructs for the shell. `cmd1 && cmd2` runs first `cmd1` then, if it returns a truthy value (zero), runs `cmd2`.